# Shadow Drive CLI for Creating Storage Account not working

Tags: shadow-drive

I was trying to create a storage account on shadow drive, using their CLI commands. But it gives error as shown below after timing out. I have 5 SHDW in the wallet I am using and I am just trying to buy 1 GB of storage. This is the first time I am working with shadow drive so any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

× Error processing transaction. See below for details:
Error: Server response status code: 400

Server response status message: Timed out awaiting confirmation on transaction

Comment: There's no image. Could you give the error?

Comment: @JacobCreech , Ohh sorry , forgot to upload it, I get this error: 

× Error processing transaction. See below for details:
Error: Server response status code: 400

Server response status message: Timed out awaiting confirmation on transaction

Comment: Timeouts on confirmations can come from several problems:
- RPC provided was invalid, had auth issue, or did not respond
- transaction was valid, but was not confirmed within the ~2 minute timeout when sent to the solana network

You should first confirm that your RPC is correct by using the CLI commands for fetching account state of an already existing storage account. If this succeeds and your transaction has the same error on multiple attempts, there is likely an issue with your CLI command.

For a better answer, please edit your question to include the CLI command you are using